# How to store matrices of different sizes (like a cell array in Matlab)?

Tags: python, list, cell

I am writing Python code (and also relatively new to Python) to do some classification using neural networks. The number of neurons in the hidden layers varies, which means I have various matrices of different size that I want to save.

If this were MATLAB, I would just do

```
for layer_iteration = 1 : number_of_layers
    cell_matrix{layer_iteration} = create_matrix(size_current, size_previous)
end
```

which would store different sized matrices in cell_matrix{layer_iteration}.

I wasn't quite sure how to do this in Python, so my first thought was to create the matrices at each iteration, flatten them, and append them. Then I create an index matrix of the same size as the flattened array, where each value is an integer, which points to the correct layer_iteration. I can then used indexing in later operations to find the correct slice of the 1D matrix and reshape. This is some of the code:

```
layer_sizes = [2, 10 ,6 ,2]
total_amount_of_values = 92 e.g. 2*10 + 10*6 + 6*2
W = np.zeros(total_amount_of_values)
idx_W = np.zeros((total_amount_of_values,), dtype=np.int)

it_idx = 0
for idx, val in enumerate(layer_sizes):

    to_idx = idx + 1

    if idx == 0:
       start_idx = 0
    else:
       start_idx = end_idx

    if it_dx < len(layer_sizes)-1:
       tmp_W = create_matrix(val, layer_sizes[to_idx])
       end_idx = start_idx + layer_sizes[idx + 1] * val
       W[start_idx:end_idx] = tmp_W
       idx_W[start_idx:end_idx] = int(it_idx)

    it_idx += 1
```

If I want to use W for matrix multiplication later on, all I need to do is:

```
tmp_W = W[idx_W == iteration]
tmp_W = np.reshape(tmp_W, (size_1, size_2))
```

This works fine but I've realised it doesn't seem Pythonic at all. I am now at a part of my code, where using my technique is complicating things. I would really benefit of a simpler way of storing different size matrices both in terms of my current code and more importantly, my education in Python.

What would be the best solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Use a container like a `list` or `dict`

Comment: So would this be the pythonic way of doing this:

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: So like this?

`cell_matrix = [ [] ]

`for idx in range(4):`
`     different_sized_matrix = create_matrix()`
`     if idx == 0:`
         `cell_matrix[idx] = different_sized_matrix`
`     else:`
         `cell_matrix.append(different_sized_matrix`

Comment: Uh, why are you making a list with one element, which you then overwrite on the first iteration, then subsequently use `.append`? Just use `.append` ... so `cell_matrix = []`, then,  `for idx, val in enumerate(layer_sizes): cell_matrix.append(create_matrix(val, layer_sizes[idx])`

Comment: Thanks! Pretty simple in retrospect...